# Problem with retrain.py. Getting error tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using `retrain.py` to retrain an object detector on photos of my hand (to detect how many fingers I'm holding). On the Tensorflow site, I followed the tutorial where I retrained it on their images of flowers. So I wrote python `retrain.py --image_dir ~/flower_photo`s and it worked. I had my `hand_photos` directory which contained sub-directories of me holding various fingers up. However I received this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /Users/spencerkraisler/hand_photos/untitled folder; No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why it's looking for some untitled folder in my `hand_photos`directory, nor why it works find on `flower_photos`.

I am using the current tensor flow and python 3.6. I am in an `anaconda` environment however this works just fine with flower_photos.

Furthermore, flower_photos just contains sub-directories of photos of various flowers, all `.jpg`. My photos are also in `.jpg` format.

Answer (score 0):

Well problem solved. I actually had an empty directory named "untitled folder" in my training data. I must've created it by accident. Case closed.